# Is there a novelization of Pandorum?

Tags: generation-ship, pandorum

Is there a novelization of Pandorum?

If not, did anyone else write about the inhabitants of a [generation ship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_ship) going feral?

Comment: Isn't this a bit like wanting a novelization of the Doom movie?

Comment: @DampeS8N: 3 stars on Amazon! [Doom](http://www.amazon.com/Doom-John-Shirley/dp/141650995X)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I've officially lost faith in humanity.

Comment: And John Shirley was once a relatively respected author...

Comment: John Shirley still _is_ a respected author in my book.  But he has bills to pay like the rest of us.  Hence the ton of novelizations he was written in the past few years (BioShock: Rapture; Aliens: Steel Egg; Predator: Forever Midnight; Doom; Constantine)

Comment: All of the answers here ignore the main part of the question and concentrate on “did anyone else write …”. This part is [not welcome here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq), we don't want questions asking for a list of works. So I'm going to say that the answer to the title question is no (I'd expect it to be mentioned on Wikipedia and IMDB anyway), and close the question.

Answer (score 4):

"*[Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphans_of_the_Sky)*" by Robert A Heinlein is a story along these lines.

Like most of RAF's work it is well worth reading.

Answer (score 4):

"[Orphans of The Sky](http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=artslinkcom-20&o=1&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&asins=0671318454)" by Robert A Heinlein.  It is very different from most of his other books and does not seem to connect into his "universe".  It has a fast plot with a space opera feel to it.

Comment: Actually, as I recall, it has a small connection to 'Time Enough for Love', where he mentions the decedents having been found, but admits to not having a list of the myths available. ""I wasn't arguing it, Ancestor. I'm a mathematical historiographer; my nose is rubbed in that fact. But has news reached here of the flight of the 'Vanguard'? The original 'Vanguard,' I mean-pre-Diaspora." Chapter: VARIATIONS ON A THEME-XIV, section Bacchanalia.

Comment: Orphans actually contains "Universe" mentioned in Matthew's answer :)

Answer (score 3):

"*Non-Stop*" by Brian Aldiss takes place aboard a generation ship.

Answer (score 3):

And in the ["*Helliconia*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helliconia) trilogy by Aldiss there is a spaceship, where the inhabitants lose contact with earth. Their society degenerates as well.

Answer (score 2):

["*Mayflies*"](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/o/kevin-odonnell-jr/mayflies.htm) by Kevin O'Donnell tells the story of a generation ship, built as an escape from a dying Earth.

Without going into too many spoilers, the central computer fails and shuts off the main drive, making the journey take much longer than expected. The passengers don't handle this well.

Answer (score 2):

[Hull Zero Three](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hull-Zero-Three-Greg-Bear/dp/0575100966/) by Greg Bear is quite similar to Pandorum. Many people have remarked on the similarities, which has cause some bad reviews. On the other hand, plenty of good reviews on Amazon too, so it's still on my list.

> Product Description
>
> HULL ZERO THREE is an edge of your seat
> thrill-ride through the darkest reaches of space, from one of the
> genre's biggest names. Perfect for fans of Arthur C. Clarke's RAMA or
> the film EVENT HORIZON. A starship hurtles through the emptiness of
> space. Its destination - unknown. Its purpose? A mystery. Its history?
> Lost. Now, one man wakes up. Ripped from a dream of a new home, a new
> planet and the woman he was meant to love in his arms, he finds
> himself wet, naked, and freezing to death. The dark halls are full of
> monsters but trusting other survivors he meets might be the greater
> danger. All he has are questions: Who is he? Where are they going?
> What happened to the dream of a new life? What happened to the woman
> he loved? What happened to Hull 03? All will be answered, if he can
> survive. Uncover the mystery. Fix the ship. Find a way home.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add [The Book of the Long Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_the_Long_Sun) tetralogy by Gene Wolf.